# Since I hadn't had much chance to communicate with you...?

Tags: correspondence, idiomatic-language

I'm asking for my guidance counselor to write me a recommendation letter for a college application but since we haven't had much conversation, so I wanted to say

> "**Since I hadn't had much chance to communicate with you**, kindly allow me to elaborate on my learning experiences in hope that you will be able to understand me better."

After this sentence I want to talk about how I moved to a foreign country and faced many struggles but how I worked up my way through the problems.

Does that sentence sound natural? And are there any other way to say this better or formally?

Is it supposed to be "much of a chance"?

Comment: As it stands the sentence is clunky and unidiomatic. An improvement might be: "As I have not had much opportunity to speak with you, may I set out my academic experience and qualifications with a view to obtaining a letter of recommendation." I assume that this is what you want to say. It is obvious that your intention is to inform your counselor so you may safely omit the final clause.

Comment: @Ronald Sole thank you for your comment. Would it be okay if I said "please allow me to elaborate on my learning experiences...."? Instead if "kindly allow me"?

Comment: @Maimai123 Have you used your dictionary to find out whether _councelor_ is a word in English? Be sure to do that if you intend to include it in your letter. But why write a letter at all? The person's job is to talk to students! Make an appointment and ask your question in person.

Comment: @Maimai123 Your suggestion looks fine to me.

Comment: Notice you yourself use the present perfect in *since we haven't had much conversation*; why, then, would you want to use the past perfect in the other sentence? As for *much of a chance*, it is informal; I would use *many opportunities*.

Answer (score 0):

*Opportunity* is a more formal equivalent to *chance*.

*Much of an opportunity* is more formal than *much opportunity*.

You can easily fix spelling mistakes such as "councelor" if you make sure your browser is checking your spelling as you type.

"Please allow me to elaborate on my learning experiences" sounds fine.

However, I don't think you really need to explain why you are giving the guidance counselor more information about you.  When a guidance counselor is responsible for several hundred students, it really isn't possible to get to know them all personally.

I hope you will make an appointment to meet with the guidance counselor in person.  Best of luck with your applications